# remove duplicate files in 2 directories

Tags: shell, files

I have two folders (w/ subfolders) containing files that both contain essentially the same content.

Example:

- `/folder/files/data/new`
- `/folder/files/data/old`

Is there way to delete all files in /new that are already in /old by *strictly filename* (NOT date modified) to prevent me from re-reading duplicate files.

Comment: Hi, definitely there is way using shell script to achieve what you are trying to do. But, it would always be better to let people know what you have tried so far and where you are struck.

Comment: I tried enedil's script below without success.

Comment: By filename, or by path? E.g. if you have `new/foo/somefile` and `new/bar/somefile`, are these duplicates or unrelated files?

Comment: You should use checksums to compare files instead of using just the filenames.

Comment: +1 @Serge files can't be duplicates by mere file names, size & checksums(MD5/SHA1, etc) must be verified.

Comment: If you have rsync installed, you could sync between your local source and destination folders with --delete option. I think that exactly does what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code below will search through not just the `old` directory but also its subdirectories and delete files from the `new` directory that have the same name and path.  This will work with all manor of hostile file names (spaces, newlines, etc.):

```
cd /folder/files/data/old || { echo "Failed to get in correct directory" ; exit 1 ; }
find . -type f -exec rm -f ../new/{} \;
```

The argument `-type f` tells `find` to look for files, not directories.  The `-exec ... \;` argument tells `find` that, once it finds a file in `old`, it should run the command `rm -f` on its counterpart in the `new` subdirectory.

Because `rm` is given the `-f` option, it will silently ignore files that don't exist.  This eliminates the need for testing for the existence of the file in `new` before attempting to delete it.  Also, it will not prompt before deleting files.  This is very handy when deleting a large number of files.  However, *be sure that you really want to delete the files before running this script*.  For protection, the script will exit with an error with an error if the `cd` command fails.